# Magento 2 - add Multiselect Status in admin Form

Tags: php, magento, module, magento2

I am developing a custom module in Magento 2. I would like to add to the editing form a multiselect to allow users to select the status of an order. In Magento 1.9 it is done in this way:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')->getResourceCollection()->getData();
```

How can this be done in Magento 2?

Comment: do you want order status options ?

Comment: Yes, i want to list all order status options.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code on {Vendor}/{Module}/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
           <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Order status</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status</source_model>
                <comment>Select the status for the orders to be exported</comment>
            </field>
```